# Kubeadmin: Why do we need to upgrade the kubelet and kubectl seperately?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

Kubeadmin is a tool to manage and maintain the Kubernetes cluster. Based on the [Kubernetes Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/#upgrade-kubelet-and-kubectl), there are rough four steps to upgrade the controlplane node.

1. upgrade the version of kubeadmin itself
2. cordon the node
3. upgrade the controlplane components with this command `kubeadm upgrade apply v1.26.x`
4. upgrade the kubelet and kubectl with this command.

   ```
   apt-mark unhold kubeadm && \
   apt-get update && apt-get install -y kubeadm=1.26.x-00 && \
   apt-mark hold kubeadm
   ```

#### Kubernetes components

Kubernetes is composed of many components, for example:

- scheduler
- etcd, a key-value storage
- API server
- kubelet
- kubectl

When executing the command `sudo kubeadm upgrade apply v1.26.x` or `kubeadm upgrade node`, the ETCD, kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler will be upgraded and restarted. Here are logs:

```
controlplane ~ ➜  kubeadm upgrade apply v1.25.0
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade] Running cluster health checks
[upgrade/version] You have chosen to change the cluster version to "v1.25.0"
[upgrade/versions] Cluster version: v1.24.0
[upgrade/versions] kubeadm version: v1.25.0
[upgrade] Are you sure you want to proceed? [y/N]: y
[upgrade/prepull] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[upgrade/prepull] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[upgrade/prepull] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[upgrade/apply] Upgrading your Static Pod-hosted control plane to version "v1.25.0" (timeout: 5m0s)...
[upgrade/etcd] Upgrading to TLS for etcd
[upgrade/staticpods] Preparing for "etcd" upgrade
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing etcd-server certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing etcd-peer certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing etcd-healthcheck-client certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Moved new manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml" and backed up old manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/tmp/kubeadm-backup-manifests-2022-12-16-08-40-41/etcd.yaml"
[upgrade/staticpods] Waiting for the kubelet to restart the component
[upgrade/staticpods] This might take a minute or longer depending on the component/version gap (timeout 5m0s)
[apiclient] Found 1 Pods for label selector component=etcd
[upgrade/staticpods] Component "etcd" upgraded successfully!
[upgrade/etcd] Waiting for etcd to become available
[upgrade/staticpods] Writing new Static Pod manifests to "/etc/kubernetes/tmp/kubeadm-upgraded-manifests2720616931"
[upgrade/staticpods] Preparing for "kube-apiserver" upgrade
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing apiserver certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing front-proxy-client certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing apiserver-etcd-client certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Moved new manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml" and backed up old manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/tmp/kubeadm-backup-manifests-2022-12-16-08-40-41/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[upgrade/staticpods] Waiting for the kubelet to restart the component
[upgrade/staticpods] This might take a minute or longer depending on the component/version gap (timeout 5m0s)
[apiclient] Found 1 Pods for label selector component=kube-apiserver
[upgrade/staticpods] Component "kube-apiserver" upgraded successfully!
[upgrade/staticpods] Preparing for "kube-controller-manager" upgrade
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing controller-manager.conf certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Moved new manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml" and backed up old manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/tmp/kubeadm-backup-manifests-2022-12-16-08-40-41/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[upgrade/staticpods] Waiting for the kubelet to restart the component
[upgrade/staticpods] This might take a minute or longer depending on the component/version gap (timeout 5m0s)
[apiclient] Found 1 Pods for label selector component=kube-controller-manager
[upgrade/staticpods] Component "kube-controller-manager" upgraded successfully!
[upgrade/staticpods] Preparing for "kube-scheduler" upgrade
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing scheduler.conf certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Moved new manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml" and backed up old manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/tmp/kubeadm-backup-manifests-2022-12-16-08-40-41/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[upgrade/staticpods] Waiting for the kubelet to restart the component
[upgrade/staticpods] This might take a minute or longer depending on the component/version gap (timeout 5m0s)
[apiclient] Found 1 Pods for label selector component=kube-scheduler
[upgrade/staticpods] Component "kube-scheduler" upgraded successfully!
[upgrade/postupgrade] Removing the old taint &Taint{Key:node-role.kubernetes.io/master,Value:,Effect:NoSchedule,TimeAdded:<nil>,} from all control plane Nodes. After this step only the &Taint{Key:node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane,Value:,Effect:NoSchedule,TimeAdded:<nil>,} taint will be present on control plane Nodes.
[upload-config] Storing the configuration used in ConfigMap "kubeadm-config" in the "kube-system" Namespace
[kubelet] Creating a ConfigMap "kubelet-config" in namespace kube-system with the configuration for the kubelets in the cluster
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[bootstrap-token] Configured RBAC rules to allow Node Bootstrap tokens to get nodes
[bootstrap-token] Configured RBAC rules to allow Node Bootstrap tokens to post CSRs in order for nodes to get long term certificate credentials
[bootstrap-token] Configured RBAC rules to allow the csrapprover controller automatically approve CSRs from a Node Bootstrap Token
[bootstrap-token] Configured RBAC rules to allow certificate rotation for all node client certificates in the cluster
[addons] Applied essential addon: CoreDNS
[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-proxy
```

```
[upgrade/successful] SUCCESS! Your cluster was upgraded to "v1.25.0". Enjoy!

[upgrade/kubelet] Now that your control plane is upgraded, please proceed with upgrading your kubelets if you haven't already done so.
```

#### Question

1. Why doesn't the command `sudo kubeadm upgrade apply v1.26.x` in step 3 upgrade the kubectl and kubelet as well?
2. why do we upgrade kubelet and kubectl in a separate step? (step 4)

#### Reference

1. Stack Overflow: [why does kubeadm do exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211251/what-does-kubeadm-do-exactly)
2. Kubernetes [Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl): kubeadm will not install or manage kubelet or kubectl for you

Answer (score 0):

The command sudo kubeadm upgrade does not upgrade kubectl and kubelet. Kubeadm only manages the control plane components, such as the API server, scheduler, and controller-manager. Kubectl and kubelet are the components that manage the nodes and workloads running on them. Therefore, they must be upgraded separately. @Ryan Lyu